# climb up the directory tree faster

Tags: bash, directory

if I'm in a very deep directory `a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j` and want to come back `a/b/c`, I have to use `../../../../../../../`.

Is there command I can pass through a number, e.g. `cd up 7`, to speed this operation up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an alias would work as a temporary solution, however if you want something more permanent that doesn't confine you to your presets I suggest writing a function to do this and including it in your .bashrc file.

[source](http://orangesplotch.com/bash-going-up/)

```
# Go up directory tree X number of directories
function up() {
        COUNTER="$@";
    # default $COUNTER to 1 if it isn't already set
if [[ -z $COUNTER ]]; then
    COUNTER=1
fi
# make sure $COUNTER is a number
if [ $COUNTER -eq $COUNTER 2> /dev/null ]; then
    nwd=`pwd` # Set new working directory (nwd) to current directory
    # Loop $nwd up directory tree one at a time
    until [[ $COUNTER -lt 1 ]]; do
        nwd=`dirname $nwd`
        let COUNTER-=1
    done
    cd $nwd # change directories to the new working directory
else
    # print usage and return error
    echo "usage: up [NUMBER]"
    return 1
fi
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using all uppercase variable names to avoid accidentally overriding special shell variables or environment variables. Also a good idea to make variables local to the function.

Comment: This code doesn't pass [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and the cd-ing is more complicated than it needs to be, plus the style is bad. Use [geirha's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/110932/301745) instead.

Answer (score 8):

You could write a function like this:

```
up() {
    local path i
    for (( i=0; i < $1; i++ )); do
        path+=../
    done
    cd "$path"
}
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc`, then you can run e.g. `up 7` to go up 7 directories. You could override cd to allow `cd up 7` too, but just making a new command is shorter and less hassle.

Comment: Similar function [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/791957/301745), but I like yours better cause it automatically handles `OLDPWD`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are toggling between 2 directories, you can use `cd -` to switch between both.

If you want to bookmark a few directories that you would probably `cd` to often, use `pushd` and `popd` -> google for more information.

Or, if you know you have to `cd` to 7th grand parent very often, you could create an alias, like:

```
alias cd7up='cd ../../../../../../../'
```

Comment: i don't like alias solution but you taught me `pushd` and `popd` which are really useful

Comment: isn't the solution useful? why was it downvoted??

Answer (score 3):

Be concise.

```
alias c1='cd ../'
alias c2='c1; c1'
alias c3='c2; c1'
alias c4='c3; c1'
alias c5='c4; c1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create aliases to do the work:

```
alias cd..2="cd ../.."
alias cd..3="cd ../../.."
alias cd..4="cd ../../../.."
alias cd..5="cd ../../../../.."
```

And then you can just type `cd..5` to go up 5 levels.

To make those aliases available in future logins, you can add the above to the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.

Comment: `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 2):

Coming from the Windows world, Alt + Up Arrow navigates to the parent directory
in Windows Explorer. So I made something like this in `~/.inputrc`:

```sh
"\33\33[A": "cd ..\n"
```

then pressing Alt + Up Arrow moves to the parent directory in the terminal. You
have to press multiple times of course to move higher, but I have found it to be
very fast. Also you can change the shortcut to your liking.

Comment: Haven't tried it but it sounds perfect. Beyond the scope of this question is it would be nice to use `Alt`+`Down Arrow` after to move back to previous child directory.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you could probably use something with `$OLDPWD`

Comment: I was thinking for up arrow call `pushd` and down arrow call `popd`: https://opensource.com/article/19/8/navigating-bash-shell-pushd-popd

Answer (score 0):

```
function cdl() {

        local arguments;
        local level_string;
        local counter=1;
        # first argument is how many levels you wish to traverse
        local level=$1; 

        # grab any argument after the initial levels you wish to traverse
        for var in "$@"; do
                if [ $counter -gt 1 ]; then
                        arguments="$arguments/$var";
                fi

                counter+=1;
        done

        # build string based on how many levels you want to go up
        if [ $level -gt 1 ]; then
                counter=1;

                while [ $counter -le $level ]; do
                        level_string="../$level_string";
                        let counter+=1;
                done
        fi

        # execute command
        cd $level_string$arguments
}

# Example:
#-----------------
# /usr/local/src/test/directory/blah> cdl 3 i want to be here
```

or

```
# /usr/local/src/test/directory/blah> cdl 3 i/want/to/be/here
```

result:

```
# /usr/local/src/i/want/to/be/here> 
#-----------------
```

Of course I also add aliases in my `.bashrc` file using the above function

```
alias cd2='cdl 2'
alias cd3='cdl 3'
alias cd4='cdl 4'
alias cd5='cdl 5'
```

Answer (score -1):

Using aliases with dots as names:

```
alias ..='cd ../'
alias ...='cd ../../'
alias ....='cd ../../../'
alias .....='cd ../../../../'
alias ......='cd ../../../../../'
```

Comment: Somehow I affraid this might break in interesting ways. Have you tried this solution on your own ubuntu?

Comment: Works for me in ZSH on Debian. I am also open to scenarios where it will break. :) The ones who want to be on the secure side may prepend the aliases with a string or a character e.g. "c..", "c..." and so on.