# How can I move down one directory

Tags: command-line, bash

I know the command for moving up one directory is `cd ..`

Is there any command to move down one directory?

Comment: How is bash supposed to know which subdirectory you want to `cd` to?

Comment: Maybe you need `cd -` , it will take you to previous directory, in case you are trying to revert from `cd ..`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way by which you want to go down by one  directory is not possible because there is only one parent directory which is denoted by `..`, but there can be multiple directories inside a directory and thus you have to mention the one you mean. You have to use `cd example` to move down by one onto the directory `example`.

But there is a shortcut: use <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion for this. To move down by one into the `example` directory, you could enter `cd e` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and if `example` is the only directory beginning with `e` the shell will automatically complete the command to `cd example`. If there are others beginning with `e`, double <kbd>Tab</kbd> will list matches, and you can type `ex` or whatever is needed and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and so on.

Comment: And if there's only one subdirectory, TAB will automatically fill it in even if you don't type any letters.

Comment: Tab won't type the wrong directory. It will only expand to as much is unique, then you have to enter more characters. If you press Tab again it will show all the possible completions.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you're right. I think Smit is thinking of Windows, which does have that behaviour.

Comment: @Barmar "tab will type wrong directory "mean it will type something other directory with same first chars which OP doesn't want if there are multiple directories.

Comment: @SMITPATIL As I mentioned above, Bash doesn't do that, but CMD and PowerShell do.

Comment: @wjandrea it happens in Linux too,I still confuse what it bash the  exactly(i am noob,using Ubuntu mate since last 4 months) !!

Comment: @SMITPATIL It's not part of the OS, it may depend on what shell you use.

Comment: @Barmar but i had find that it works almost every where!! i had tried so many disrtos

Comment: Did you really try it when you have more than one subdirectory that starts with the same letter? Create subdirectories `abcd` and `abcx`, then type `a` and TAB. It will just add `abc`, not `abcd` or `abcx`.

Comment: @Barmar edited.

Answer (score 15):

The main difference between moving up a directory, and moving down a directory, in the directory tree is:

- Moving up - there is only one option, hence the command doesn't need to mention the folder name:

  `cd ..`
- Moving down - there might be several sub-directories, hence you first need to choose sub-directory, to change directory *down* into *example-dir* the command is:

  `cd example-dir`

Comment: Well; `..` *is* the name of the directory. It's just the name of the *parent* directory, which is present in every directory in the file system. So technically you *are* naming the directory that you want to move into to `cd`.

Answer (score 13):

In older versions of bash (e.g: 4.3) you could do `cd *` and it would go to the first sub directory it found:

```
$ ls
dir1/   dir2/   dir3/

$ cd *
```

Now we are in `dir1/`.

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can move up cause because there is one directory but when we talk about going down there can be more than one that is why we have `ls` we will list all the available directory and then we change directory one down in which we needed to go by the command `cd examle1`.

```
$ ls
dir1 dir2 sir3
$ cd dir1
$ cd ..
$ cd dir2
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer exactly the question that was asked, but as was pointed out by someone else, that question didn't really make sense anyway.

But here is the answer to a nearby question. To *go back* to the directory from whence you came, use `cd -`

```
[mike@gwydion Work]$ cd ..
[mike@gwydion ~]$ cd -
/home/mike/Work
[mike@gwydion Work]$
```

If you want to save a directory for later reference, do some stuff in between in a bunch of other directories, and then go back, use `pushd` and `popd`:

```
[mike@gwydion Work]$ pushd .
~/Work ~/Work
[mike@gwydion Work]$ cd ~/Temp/
[mike@gwydion Temp]$ run some command

[mike@gwydion Temp]$ cd ~/SourceCode/
[mike@gwydion SourceCode]$ run some command
[mike@gwydion SourceCode]$ popd
~/Work
[mike@gwydion Work]$ popd
bash: popd: directory stack empty
[mike@gwydion Work]$
```

Answer (score 0):

`cdd` is a small bash script that's a power tool for the `cd` command. Visit the link below for a one minute video and copy the code below if you like what you see.

[cdd - a Change Directory (cd) Power Tool](https://www.pippim.com/programs.html#cdd)

It's annoying have to type out long sub-directory names with spaces. So I created a little function in `~/.bashrc` that automatically changes down one sub-directory level if there is only one sub-directory. If there is more than one sub-directory then `zenity` is used to pick one to change to.

```
cdd () {

    OFS="$IFS"                                  # Save Input File Separator
    IFS=$'\n'
    # Bash array of directories names
    dirs=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep './' | cut -c 3- | sort) )

    # If no directories exit
    if [ "${#dirs}" -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "No subdirectories"
        IFS="$OFS"                              # Restore Input File Separator
        return
    fi

    # Only one directory then change to it and exit
    if [ "${#dirs[@]}" -eq 1 ] ; then
        cd "${dirs[0]}"
        IFS="$OFS"                              # Restore Input File Separator
        return
    fi

    # Zenity to pick one of the directories
    result=$(zenity --list --width=600 --height=400 --title="down" \
             --column="Sub-Directories" "${dirs[@]}" \
             2> >(grep -v 'GtkDialog' >&2))     # Suppress Gtk annoying message
    IFS="$OFS"                                  # Restore Input File Separator
             
    if [ ! -z "$result" ] ; then                # Did they select an item?
        cd "$result"
    fi
}
```

Copy above code into your `~/.bashrc` file and then open a terminal and type `cdd` to use it.

If terminal is already open, you can resource your revised `~/.bashrc` file with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

---

## Usage

When you call `cdd` and there is more than one sub-directory you need to pick one:

[image: cdd.png]

In this screen if you click **OK** button it is equivalent to:

```
cd Seven\ Mary\ Three
```

or:

```
cd "Seven Mary Three"
```

When you call `cdd` and there is only one sub-directory it automatically changes to it:

```
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three$ cdd
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$
```

When you call `cdd` and there are no sub-directories an error is displayed:

```
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$ cdd
No subdirectories
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$
```