# Script that chooses one subdirectory in directory

Tags: bash, scripts, directory

Need to write a script, that choose one subdirectory in directory to use it.

I see it in this way.

1. This is /SampleDir/ and it has /SubDir1/, /SubDir2/ and /SubDir3/
2. User enter the directory location, program search it and give to user list of SubDirectories in this Dir, user choose with exactly subdir he want to work just click the number of list:
3. Code

```
echo "Сhoose Directory:\n"
read SOMEDIR
//  #check nubmber of subdirs
echo "In directory you have multiple subdir's, which one do you want to use"
// #choose subdir
// #Any operation, like Remove SubDir
```

4. And same in Terminal

Choose Directory:

**input:** /root/Documents/SampleDir/

In directory you have multiple subdir's, which one do you want to use:

1)SubDir1

2)SubDir2

3)SubDir3

**Input**: 1

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930334/how-can-i-move-down-one-directory/1276376#1276376) to select long sub-directory names that are time consuming to type.

## Usage

When you call `cdd` and there is more than one sub-directory you need to pick one:

[image: cdd.png]

In this screen if you click **OK** button it is equivalent to:

```
cd Seven\ Mary\ Three
```

or:

```
cd "Seven Mary Three"
```

When you call `cdd` and there is only one sub-directory it automatically changes to it:

```
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three$ cdd
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$
```

When you call `cdd` and there are no sub-directories an error is displayed:

```
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$ cdd
No subdirectories
rick@alien:~/Music/Seven Mary Three/American Standard$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the directory list in an array

```
mapfile -d '' -t dirs < <(printf '%s\0' */)
```

and then use the bash `select` construct:

```
select d in "${dirs[@]}"; do echo "You chose: $d"; break; done
1) Desktop/           3) dir/               5) opt/               7) somedir/           9) subdir/
2) Documents/         4) openssh-8.2p1/     6) qgis_sample_data/  8) src/
#? 5
You chose: opt/
```

Replace the `echo` with whatever you actually want to do with the  selected directory.