# Shell - Navigate up 'n' directories

Tags: command-line

I often find myself doing commands like this

```
cd ../../../../../
```

Is there a shortcut I can use that will cd ../ *n times*?

Comment: Are absolute paths a permitted solution?

Comment: [Expand dots to dot-dot component](https://github.com/bac0n/bash_completion)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [climb up the directory tree faster](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110922/climb-up-the-directory-tree-faster) - personally I like [geirha's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/110932/301745) the best.

Comment: Or this one https://askubuntu.com/a/703701/295286  Pretty much all solutions revolve around the same idea

Comment: @wjandrea I voted to close but then retracted my vote since the linked question specifies [[tag:bash]] while Zsh and csh solutions can be found on this page.

Comment: @Melebius Also this question is much more popular than the older one now. When I commented they were on about the same level. I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: Not directly related, but if you're always traveling to a set of common folders you could use a script like [`z`](https://github.com/rupa/z) to let you jump to folders from anywhere. Just `z Documents` to go there, for example

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, there is no existing command for this, but it is trivial to write one. Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` file (thanks to D. Ben Knoble for [pointing out](https://askubuntu.com/a/1202320/85695) that the variable should be `local`):

```
function ncd(){
  local path=""
  for ((i=1;i<=$1;i++)); do
    path="../$path"
  done
  echo "Moving to $path" >&2
  cd "$path"
}
```

Save the file, open a new terminal, and you can now move N directories up using `ncd N`. For example:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/dir7/dir8/dir9
$ ncd 5
Moving to ../../../../../
$ pwd
/home/terdon/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4
$ ncd 2
Moving to ../../
$ pwd
/home/terdon/dir1/dir2
```

Answer (score 16):

Coming from the Windows world, Alt + Up Arrow navigates to the parent directory
in Windows Explorer. So I made something like this in `~/.inputrc`:

```sh
"\33\33[A": "cd ..\n"
```

then pressing Alt + Up Arrow moves to the parent directory in the terminal. You
have to press multiple times of course to move higher, but I have found it to be
very fast. Also you can change the shortcut to your liking.

Comment: Thanks. Quite a nice solution

Comment: This is wonderful. I had trouble getting the arrow keys to bind under Debian, so I used Alt-u instead:

`"\eu": "cd ..\n"`

.inputrc can be immediately reloaded with bind -f ~/.inputrc

Answer (score 15):

You can easily create aliases or shell functions to perform the given task. I personally use these:

```
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
```

and so on, manually defined for up to many-many dots in my `.bashrc`.

A shell function could instead easily take a numeric parameter, and execute `cd ..` in a loop that many times.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to @terdon's answer, with slightly more natural usage and output:

```
# go up
up() {
  local count="${1:-1}"
  local path=../
  while (( --count > 0 )) ; do
    path="$path"../
  done
  echo "cd -- $path"
  cd -- "$path"
}
```

This defines a function `up`, which has the following properties:

- `up n` will go up `n` directories
- `up` will go up exactly one directory (i.e., the default for `n` is 1)
- output mimics that when using `shopt -s autocd` (hence the `--`, which are
  technically unnecessary)
- as before, `OLDPWD` is set correctly to the current value of `PWD`, rather
  than one of the intermediate directories. This means that `up 5; cd -` works
  as expected.

Comment: Similar? That's the same, only more confusing.

Comment: I guess "torek" is me? :) Your addition of `local` makes a lot of sense, I should have thought of that myself! Then, you are defaulting to `cd ../` when no input is passed, which is also good, but you don't actually explain any of these benefits, so they aren't obvious to the novice.  The `--` is pointless since you know the argument will always be a variation of `../`. And you could simplify to `while (( --count > 0 )) ; do` to avoid the needless repetition of `(( count-- ))`. But this is indeed a better version than mine, it's a shame you don't point out the benefits.

Comment: @terdon eek! Sorry I was thinking of torek, who i see in tag:git a lot. Updates coming eventually.

Comment: @rexkogitans what's confusing? I'd love to know to increase the readability.

Comment: I admit that a function should declare all variables as `local`. My point in saying it's more confusing is - maybe subjective: `for` is more readable than `while` with a predecrement. Also, what does `${1:-1}` do? If i did not oversee something, that's the same as just `$1`. I would also quote everything, like `path="${path}../"`.

Comment: *What does `${1:-1}` do*--see `man bash`, and look under Parameter Expansion (*Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.*) The while is subjective, but I'm not convinced I should change it. Reasonable point about the quotes though

Answer (score 4):

Using [the printf hack](https://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times):

```
function updir(){
    cd $(printf '../%.0s' {1..$1})
}
```

E.G. `updir 5` will move you up 5 directories.

Comment: Yes, very clever ! The `0` also can be dropped, so `printf '../%.s'` works just as well

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to consider is physically sending the keys if you have `xdotool`:

```
xdotool type ../
```

Assign it to a keyboard hotkey through Keyboard -> Shortcuts dialog. Then you can press the hotkey a required number of times.

Answer (score 2):

If you use zsh you can use repeat:

```
repeat 5 { cd ..}
```

Comment: In [t]csh, `repeat 5 cd ..` works. (I can’t figure out how to get it to work with braces.)

Answer (score 2):

In Zsh, you can simply add a single dot per level, i.e.

- `cd ...` equals to `cd ../..` and
- `cd ......` equals to `cd ../../../../..`

Unfortunately, this cannot be used together with other path components, i.e. commands like

```
cd ...../foo
```

don’t work.

See also [more tips on the `cd` command in Zsh](https://blog.confirm.ch/zsh-tips-changing-directories/).

Answer (score 1):

I have used this for years:

```
alias up=" cd .."
alias up2="cd ../.."
alias up3="cd ../../.."
alias up4="cd ../../../.."
alias up5="cd ../../../../.."
alias up6="cd ../../../../../.."
alias up7="cd ../../../../../../.."
alias up8="cd ../../../../../../../.."
alias up9="cd ../../../../../../../../.."
```